# Run .exe on Windows CE 8.0

Tags: python, windows, exe, pyinstaller, windows-ce

I'm trying to start a .exe-file on my machine which is running Windows CE 8.00.

The .exe-file was generated with the help of PyInstaller (https://www.pyinstaller.org/) which converted my Python script to such a file. I used a laptop running Windows 10 for this operation.

The .exe-file runs as intended on other laptops (also Windows 10) but when I try to run it on the intended machine with Windows CE 8.00 I get an error message displayed: *File.exe is not a valid Windows Embeded Compact application.*

Information about the machine:

- Windows 8.00 Build 6270
- Processor Type: AMD Steppe Eagle

I'm completely clueless where to start to look for an alternative solution. Online there is not much information about this topic.

I've tryed dowloading Python CE (https://sourceforge.net/projects/pythonce/) but when starting the .exe-file for the installation I've got the same error message as before: *... is not a valid Windows Embeded Copact application".

Comment: The error is pretty clear. That executable wasn't built for Windows CE. Windows CE is an *embedded* version of Windows which means it's tailored to each device's hardware, can run on x86 or ARM, and contains only the drivers selected by the device's manufacturer and offers a limited set of APIs. A coffee machine doesn't need a network card after all, so it makes no sense to include the network stack. You can't use an executable built for Windows on an embedded device when most of the APIs and libraries it needs aren't there

Comment: BTW you'd have the same (if not worse) problem with Linux too. You'd have to compile your application to run on the specific, custom distribution created by the device manufacturer, without the ability to use predefined target platforms the way you can with Windows CE.

Comment: As for Python CE - that's a 13 year old program that's guaranteed to *not* run on any modern Windows CE version. The screenshots are from the Pocket PC (ie PDA) era - before even iPhones. It was more of a proof-of-concept too, as Python (and any interpreted language) was way too slow for the embedded devices of the time.

Comment: Instead of creating a program with a generic language for a generic platform and then trying to shoehorn it into an embedded device, you have to start from the other end. Find out what that device supports, what tools are available and **use them**, not your generic language. You aren't building a web site. The primary drivers aren't programmer productivity, they are about performance, efficiency and power usage.

Answer (score 3):

Windows CE is not compatible with Windows (NT,XP,7,8 or 10), it's a different OS that share similar APIs.
There's no way to run the same exe on both. You may be able to build two executables (WinCE and Windows) from the same code base, but that depends on the language and I am not aware of tools converting python to native WinCE exe.